# Avoid Converting DateTimeOffset to UTC time in Azure EventGrid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I've been testing out Azure's EventGrid and one of the things I'm trying to do is send an event where part of the PayLoad is a DateTimeOffset field.  I'm publishing the event using the standard EventGridClient:

```
using (var client = new EventGridClient(topicCredentials))
{
    await client.PublishEventsAsync(topicHostname, eventGridEvents).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I've fired up Fiddler and verified that the date portion is getting serialized as I would expect: 
"CheckInDate": "2018-12-26T14:47:42.8-08:00"

But when my subscribed Azure Functions listener receives the HttpTrigger and reads the message's content, the same item has somehow been formatted as UTC: "CheckInDate": "2018-12-26T22:47:42.8+00:00".

Is there a setting or something I need to enable to get it to preserve the original offset?

Comment: There's a [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909934-azure-event-grid/suggestions/37672006-bug-feature-support-datetimeoffset-instead-conver) regarding this issue. Please consider voting for it :-)

Comment: Apparently the above uservoice has been fixed. You need to use Cloud Event Schema v1.0

Answer (score 1):

Although working with **UTC** on the backend is usually the best practice (so I would consider keeping it unless there is a specific need to work with local time), I think you should try to store the offset in a dedicated field, and the just convert it back to the relevant local time on the receiving side using that offset.

Take a look at [DateTimeOffset Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) on how you might be able to do the conversions.

Hope it helps!